# marking box in an image from response request python

Tags: python, opencv, python-requests, response

```
import requests
import cv2
frame=cv2.imread('C:\\Users\\aaa\\Downloads\\abc.jpg')
url = 'https://app.nanonets.com/api/v2/ObjectDetection/Model/4729a79f-ab19-4c1b-8fe9'

data = {'file': open('C:\\Users\\aaa\\Downloads\\abc.jpg', 'rb')}

response = requests.post(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('S5zsN-yFZJxRH9tMwsaHUCxJg3dZaDWj', ''), files=data)
print (type(response))
print(response)
```

I uploaded an image for object detection. I got the response like this.

```
{"message":"Success","result":[{"message":"Success","input":"abc.jpg","prediction":[{"label":"car","xmin":411,"ymin":332,"xmax":585,"ymax":462,"score":0.99097943},{"label":"car","xmin":496,"ymin":170,"xmax":592,"ymax":248,"score":0.96399206},{"label":"car","xmin":223,"ymin":147,"xmax":294,"ymax":202,"score":0.9383388},{"label":"car","xmin":164,"ymin":130,"xmax":230,"ymax":175,"score":0.8968652},{"label":"car","xmin":448,"ymin":489,"xmax":623,"ymax":540,"score":0.8311123}],"page":0,"request_file_id":"5a8549f1-fb2c-487a-83b5-234608b3168b","filepath":"uploadedfiles/4729a79f-ab19-fac0fb807e6d/PredictionImages/53207.jpeg"}]}
```

I want to make a box in the image with the given coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please make sure to format your code so it is easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
import cv2
import math 
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw 
import json

frame=cv2.imread('C:\Users\aaa\Downloads\abc.jpg')
url = 'https://app.nanonets.com/api/v2/ObjectDetection/Model/4729a79f-ab19-4c1b-8fe9'
data = {'file': open('C:\Users\aaa\Downloads\abc.jpg', 'rb')}
response = requests.post(url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('S5zsN-yFZJxRH9tMwsaHUCxJg3dZaDWj', ''), files=data)

predictions = json.loads(response.text)['result'][0]['prediction']
img = Image.open('C:\Users\aaa\Downloads\abc.jpg')
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)   

for prediction in predictions:  
    shape = [(prediction['xmin'], prediction['ymin']), (prediction['xmax'], prediction['ymax'])]     
    img1.rectangle(shape, fill ="# ffff33", outline ="red") 
img.show()
```